# Can "predeceased" be used before any event?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

When a person dies, it is common to say the person was predeceased by other people such as his parents, his brother, and others.

However, I am wondering if these statements are correct:

> - His brother predeceased his birth.
> - Their child predeceased their marriage.

In these cases, "predeceased" means "died before".  But is "predeceased" valid here? Or is it only valid before another death event, as in:

> - His brother predeceased him/his death.

There are various definitions of the meaning of "predeceased". Some refer only to preceding another person's death, but others such as [at Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/predeceased) (based on the Random House Dictionary) give the definition of "predeceased" as:

> "to die before (another person, the occurrence of an event, etc.)"

And there is some legal use of "predeceased" with respect to events that are not necessarily a death event, such as [this definition of Survive](http://www.courts.state.co.us/Glossary.cfm):

> "Survive: An individual than has neither predeceased an event,
>   including the death of another individual, or is deemed to have
>   predeceased an event under §15-11-104, §15-11-702 and §15-11-712
>   C.R.S."

[Searching on Google for "predeceased the event"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22predeceased%20the%20event%22) gives 21,100 results, many of which are from legal documents.

So my question is, in proper English, is it proper to use the word "predeceased" when referring to events other than a death, such as a birth or a marriage or any other event, even something like the sinking of the Titanic?

In other words, is "predeceased" allowed everywhere you could write "died before"?

Comment: What do you want those sentences to say? That his brother's birth was first? What is the "marriage" sentence supposed to mean? [These questions do indicate that you ***can't*** used "predecease" in this way. But clarification would help the community to provide the correct word.]

Comment: "His birth was predeceased by his brother" implies to me that his brother died before he was born. Is that what you mean?
"Their marriage was predeceased by their child" implies to me that the child died before the marriage happened. Is that what you mean?

Comment: *Predeceased* only means that one person died before another person died. It cannot be used in an other fashion, such as one person dying and the other person going shopping.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I'm updating the statements to clarify.

Comment: @MattЭллен - Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Is it valid to say this?

Comment: @lkessler No, you cannot use predecease that way.  You predecease a person, not an event, and it means that that other person died after you did.

Comment: @tchrist - You should give that as a possible answer, because that's what I want to know.

Comment: I think that you are actually looking for some word for *precognition*, like: *foreseen*, *predicted*, *anticipated*… etc

Comment: No, I am looking for how to express that a person actually died before some specific event like a birth or a marriage.

Comment: I fail to see why this question is being closed.

Comment: I suggest consulting [the Dictionary’s entry for *predeceased*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/266467), which states: "*adj.* Chiefly in legal contexts.  Of a person: that has died before another person, esp. a spouse or next of kin; previously deceased. Also occas. *fig*." If a person predeceases his political party, then he has died before his own political party dies. Note that parties are not alive and therefore can only die in an extended, figurative sense. This makes even less sense if you try to stretch it to say that he predeceases his birthday party.

Comment: @mplungjan Because the definition of the word is [General Reference](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/266467).

Comment: @tchrist - That General Reference link you give is not a good one because it requires login at that site.

Comment: @lkessler It is the best possible link because it actually contains the history of the word and its use over time, along with citations demonstrating these shifting meanings. Plus access happens to be free this week, so there is no excuse. (I actually don’t consider that an excuse: believe it or not, real scholarship entails more than a google.  It requires cracking actual books and real thought. If the answer is in a standard reference work, then it is General Reference. And this is.)

Comment: But it ISN'T - the examples from play, legal texts and other books show that the word indeed HAS and IS used to denote that a persone died before someTHING else and not just someONE else. The Oxford ref does not show an example of a person who predeceased the war for example

Comment: @tchrist - That is a subscription site that only has institutional free trials. I don't see any free access this week, and even if there is, it won't help people who read this question a week from now. You've commented a lot on the question and the other answers to this question. Why don't you add your own answer, and in that you can quote the definition of the word from the General Reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[predecease](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/predeceases) Legal dictionary:

> die before someone else, as "if my brother, Harry, should predecease me, his share of my estate I give to his son, Eugene."

[predecease](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predecease) Merriam/Webster:

> to die before (another person)

[predecease](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/predeceased) reference.com

> to die before (another person, the occurrence of an event, etc.).

Here is a UK reference to try

[Over 5,206,000 obituaries, death notices, wedding announcements and all other family announcements, from 511 newspapers, updated daily.](http://www.iannounce.co.uk/United-Kingdom/23?_fstatus=search;keywords=predeceased)

> - His wife predeceased him
> - Predeceased by his wife
> - Predeceased by husband ... and grandson ...

[Google NGram predeceased](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=predeceased&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

> - predeceased by his son
> - predeceased issue !!!
> - predeceased beneficiary

So we also found

> “Survive” means that an individual has neither predeceased an event, including the death of another individual, nor is deemed to have predeceased an event.

and

> Consulars are duly congratulated who predeceased the war between Pompeius and Caesar

I found one blog post by an individual which does not prove anything

> Sadly, Lucy's mother, Lucy Dupuy Craig Woolfolk, predeceased the wedding event by 14 >years.

but I also found a lot of

> his father predeceased the birth

**My conclusion**: it IS used with events, but I cannot say if it can be used with **any** event.
People will understand it, but if this is a legal issue, you need to talk to a lawyer

Comment: There are some references, such as at Dictionary.com (based on the Random House Dictionary) that give the definition of "predeceased" as: "to die before (another person, the occurrence of an event, etc.)" - See: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/predeceased

Comment: Ah, I see------

Comment: Also, I've found some legal use of "predeceased" with respect to events that are not necessarily a death event, such as this definition of "Survive: An individual than has neither predeceased an event, including the death of another individual, or is deemed to have predeceased an event under §15-11-104, §15-11-702 and §15-11-712 C.R.S." at http://www.courts.state.co.us/Glossary.cfm#S

Comment: Yeah, I found this one too when adding "an" _Survive” means that an individual has neither predeceased an event, including the death of another individual, nor is deemed to have predeceased an event._

Comment: If you want to use websearches as "proof" or "disproof" of the use of a phrase, why not search for "predeceased the birth", "predeceased the marriage" or "predeceased the event". The latter has 21,100 results on Google, many of which are from legal documents.

Comment: I'm adding these definitions into my questions to clarify it.

Comment: When do you propose that events “die”, that they might be said to have been predeceased by someone or other?

Comment: Not events that die, that soemone dies before an event and not just another person

Answer (score 2):

> The New Jersey Estate Law says a divorced spouse is considered
>   predeceased to that of the testor. Therefore it is clear that
>   predeceased can be used in conjunction with an event. In this case, a
>   divorce was the event that regarded the spouse predeceased to that of
>   the testor's death even though the spouse lived on past the testor's
>   death. Alive but considered by law predeceased via divorce.

Those who think predeceased is only about death of someone need to update to the current trend of predeceased applies to events also. 
As law has already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Predecease mean someone died before a event or person. For example you basically said the marriage was dead before the child was born. I would have said "their marriage preceded the birth of their child."

Comment: No, it does not mean that. *Predecease* mean one person died before another person died.

Comment: This is as I understood it, that "Predecease means someone died before an event or person." I am specifically interested in its usage prior to an event. How do I properly use it in that case?

Answer (score -2):

By dissecting the word "predeceased," one can conclude it would mean 'before death." It is generally a jargonistic term used by lawyers and funeral directors, both of which use the word liberally and without much thought of the overall awkward sentence construction. For example, "Bill was predeceased by his parents." By examining the sentence, one could conclude Bill died before his parents, as most people associate "pre" with before. A better practice would be to say "Bill's parents died before him," and eliminate any vagueness.

Comment: it's a shortening of "preceded in death" rather than "before death"