# A term to describe a deceased relative who died before you were born

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My paternal grandfather died before I was born, and my father assigned his given-name to my middle-name to honour his memory.

I could describe him as "my late grandfather" but "late" simply means deceased - I'm wondering if there's a word or short phrase to describe a relative who had a somewhat untimely death (he died in his 60s) that would otherwise have been around to see me grow up.

Basically a more succinct version of "my died-before-I-was-born grandfather".

(Secondarily, should my question say "...that would otherwise have been..." or "...that would have otherwise have been..."? The repetition of "have" seems incorrect, but lacking it also feels incorrect).

Comment: I think you are stuck with "....my paternal grandfather, who died before I was born."

Comment: I'm not sure in what context it would be important to mention your grandfather AND the fact that he died before you were born, other than mentioning his being deceased as an incidental remark. An incidental remark like this is typically just addressed in its own independent phrase. If there were a context where it would be used repeatedly, it might deserve its own term or word. Do you have any clarification to add about the context that would suggest it deserves its own term or word? I can't think of any.

Comment: If someone dies before you do, they *[predecease](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111690)* you, but I can think of no word for someone who dies before you are born.

Comment: You can say something like *I was named after my already-deceased grandfather*. The implication is that his death occurred before the naming, which is assumed to be when you were born.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could say, 'I was called (your name) in memory of my grandfather'. 'In memory of' would clearly imply that he was no longer alive when the name was given.